# Adding user input to run path to collect data

Tags: shell, scripting

I am trying to read the number of lines in a .list file but the .list file is deep inside a folder. my codes are as above:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo -e "Enter file location: \c"
read filename

filepath=/filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list
filefinalpath=$filename + $filepath

cd $filefinalpath

if [ -e "$filefinalpath" ]
then
total=$(grep -c "#" -c -v $filefinalpath)
echo -e "There are $total lines"
else
echo $filefinalpath not found
fi
```

my codes are definetly wrong, but my idea is lets say a user inputs the front part, it adds on to the `$fileaddpath` to cd into the final folder.
for example user keys in `project/user123/folder1` . This is then combined with `filepath=/filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list` To get a final output of

cd `project/user123/folder1/filebig/filemedium/filesmall/data.list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change line:

```
filefinalpath=$filename + $filepath
```

to be

```
filefinalpath="${filename}${filepath}"
```

Comment: Thanks ! i got this right thanks to you !

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

**1) `cd` stands for "change directory" and only allows moving to a directory, but will fail for a file.**

OK:

```
cd /path/to/directory
```

ERROR:

```
cd /path/to/directory/file.list
```

**2) Combining strings**

```
 stringA=foo
 stringB=bar
 newstring="$oldstring""$newstring"
```

**3) Counting lines**

I strongly suggest using `wc` for this:

```
wc -l file
```

will return the number of lines.

Comment: Thanks i got it